# IE 10 cross-domain GET aborted

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ssl, cdn

In IE10 (I don't have any other IE's to test on), I am getting `aborted` for my javascript GETs from my cdn.

I read a couple of other posts about this issue and it seems that IE may not play well with CORS. But IE 10 is supposed to have that resolved.

I heard that it may be an SSL issue.

I don't even understand the log below. How can I have a GET request with the response code being 0?

I am using internet explorer 10.0.9200. I am not using JQuery to get these assets. I am just using basic script tags.

Thanks so much for your help!

[image: My network tab]

Comment: what is triggering the Ajax call?

Comment: I just add the script tag in right before the close of the body tag.